# How to transfer object from Spring MVC to Vaadin view?

Tags: spring-mvc, vaadin

Have simple Controller get method, as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        modelAndView.setViewName("vaadinview");
        modelAndView.addObject("test_attr", "VALUE");

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Try to add object to model view and transfer to vaadin view, but I can't get this object or parameter in vaadin view 
`implements HasUrlParameter<String>` allow to get string parameter from url, but if I want to get complex object for vaadin view, How I can do it?

Comment: You pass the "id" of what you are creating and let the vaadin ui pull that id from some store. Or if you really need to decuple this, you have to serialize your object to some degree.

Answer (score 2):

You can in general not do something like that because each framework is using completely different abstractions. The fundamental operation in Spring MVC is to receive an HTTP request and based on that produce a response containing e.g. HTML or JSON. Vaadin is a framework for building single-page applications based on synchronizing a server-side component tree to the browser.

If you want to bootstrap a Vaadin component tree when the user types `somehost.com/test` into the browser's address bar, then you should let Vaadin handle that with by adding a `@Route("test")` annotation on the component to use. The default configuration with Vaadin's Spring integration will automatically register Vaadin's request handler as a fallback for any URL that isn't covered by any Spring MVC `@RequestMapping` or similar.

If one part of your application uses Spring MVC and the other uses Vaadin and some Spring MVC controller wants to forward the user to the Vaadin part, then the best approach is most likely to make the Spring MVC controller issue a redirect to a URL that is handled by Vaadin. If you want to pass along some data, then you can pass that through the redirect URL and access it using e.g. `HasUrlParameter` on the Vaadin side. Another alternative would be to put the data in the HTTP session, but then you'd have to also deal with the possibility of interference between multiple tabs in the same browser since they all share the same session.

Comment: I can set up Body for vaadin route and get this body inside vaadin route ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate?